# Aggregate spreadsheet data based on date-time ranges

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a spreadsheet containing logging data into a certain system

```
Log in time        Log out time       Id        User_type
2018-03-21 18:28   2018-03-21 19:59   1584550   S1
2018-03-21 14:57   2018-03-22 00:29   1584549   S1
2018-03-21 11:01   2018-03-21 12:01   1584548   C2
2018-03-21 01:25   2018-03-21 03:01   1584547   C2
2018-03-20 20:20   2018-03-20 21:14   1584546   S2
... (hundreds of rows) ...
```

This is data from one week, 168 hours.
What I would need is an hour-by-hour breakdown of how many people were logged in the system. The result would look something like this:

```
19/03/2018 0:00-0:59   5
19/03/2018 1:00-1:59   4
19/03/2018 2:00-2:59   6
19/03/2018 3:00-3:59   8
19/03/2018 4:00-4:59   9
-- and so on...
```

I already have a concept how to do it with a groovy script, summing it up in loops, but there might be some built in Excel function I could use for this, right?

I'd appreciate any insight, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For source data in A:D (row 1 - header), hours (with data) list in column F, use the next formula in G1:

```
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,"<" & F1,$B:$B,">" & F1)
```

Drag it down over date-hour list.

The formula counts the amount of logged users overlapped for each date-hour value (point). To count partial overlapping over range, you may edit formula (and, maybe, add one more column to date-hour list, from-till).